# Wordpress website crashes when allowoverride to All

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

**the problem is that my wordpress website works but the pages give a 404 page not found error , so i followed these steps :**

1. enabled mod_rewrite
2. my .htaccess file looks like this :

   ```
       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
       </IfModule>
   ```

3- when i edit the value in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

TO

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

the website crashes whenever i change the above value , i also tried to re install my apache server and nothing seems to work .

Comment: have you gone in the backend, page "Permalink" and save the page to flush rewrite rules.

Comment: @mmm yes i did that , and then when i allow override all  the whole website crashes

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?